# How to solve Run Time Skipping Of a Code snippet cin.getline of C++

Tags: c++, string, inheritance

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
char name[20];
char rollno[20];

public:
void input();
void display(); 
};
class Acadamic_details:public Student
{
private:
    float marks,percentage;
public:
    void input();
    void display();
};
    class Guardian_details:public Acadamic_details
    {
    private:
        char F_name[20],M_name[20];
    public:
        void input();
        void display();
    };

    void Student::input()
    {
    cout<<endl<<" Enter the Name : ";
    cin.getline(name,30,'\n');
    cout<<endl<<" Enter the Roll No :";
    cin.getline(rollno,30,'\n');
    }
    void Acadamic_details::input()
    {
    Student::input();
    cout<<endl<<" Enter the Marks out of 500 :";
    cin>>marks;
    }
    void Guardian_details::input()
    {
        Acadamic_details::input();
        cout<<endl<<" Enter the Father's Name :";
        cin.getline(F_name,30,'\n');
        cout<<endl<<" Enter the Mother's Name :";
        cin.getline(M_name,30,'\n');
    }

    void Student::display()
    {
    cout<<endl<<" Name : "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<" Roll No : "<<rollno<<endl; 
    }   
    void Acadamic_details::display()
    {
        Student::display();
        percentage=(marks/500)*100;
        cout<<endl<<" Marks : "<<marks<<"/500"<<endl;
        cout<<" Percentage : "<<percentage<<"%"<<endl;
    }
            void Guardian_details::display()
            {
                Acadamic_details::display();
                cout<<endl<<" Father's Name : "<<F_name<<endl;
                cout<<" Mother's Name : "<<M_name<<endl;
            }

   int main()
   {
   Guardian_details g1;
   cout<<" Enter the Student's Details "<<endl;
   g1.input();
   cout<<" Student's Details Are : "<<endl;
   g1.display();
   getch();
   return 0;
   }
```

This is the Implementation of Multilevel Inheritance.
There is no compilation Error encountered during Compilation.
But When I executed the Program I am facing a run time Problem

```
void Guardian_details::input()
{
    Acadamic_details::input();
    cout<<endl<<" Enter the Father's Name :";
    cin.getline(F_name,30,'\n');
    cout<<endl<<" Enter the Mother's Name :";
    cin.getline(M_name,30,'\n');
}
```

from the above Code Snippet , `cin.getline(F_name,30,'\n');` is not working.
Everytime Run the Program It directly Execute the `cout<<endl<<" Enter the Mother's Name :";
                                  cin.getline(M_name,30,'\n');`

skipping the `cin.getline(F_name,30,'\n');`.

Here is the Output Screen : [image: Output Screen]

Can anyone Explain Why is Happening so and What is the Alternative to that Code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Acadamic_details::input` when you do

```
cin>>marks;
```

the newline is left in the buffer for the next call to `getline`, which interprets it as an empty line.

Comment: How I can Resolve this ?

Comment: @KunalVerma Stop using `getline` everywhere, and only use the `>>` operator? Or use `getline` to get the numbers as well, and convert the string to a number? Or [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the next characters until the newline?

Comment: Found the Solution . ( using (cin>>marks).ignore(); )